# Updating global variable in async function not updating

Tags: javascript

I have this code that checks if a user is logged in using an `async` function and firebase:

```
  // Init Auth
  const auth = getAuth();
  let curUser = null;

  async function asyncHandler(user) {
    curUser = await user;
    console.log(curUser);
  }

  auth.onAuthStateChanged(asyncHandler);
  console.log(curUser);
```

When I `console.log(curUser)` inside the function, it prints out a value that is not null, and the variable is updated. But once I `console.log(curUser)` outside of the function, the variable returns to null. How can I go about fixing this so that `curUser` retains the value updated in the function?

Also, I have read multiple other questions on this site about this and I have heard of something called hoisting, but after reading that, it still didn't help me in fixing my code. Thanks.

Comment: `console.log(curUser);` is executed _before_ `curUser` is assigned a value inside the `async` function. Synchronous code in executed before asynchronous code.

Comment: Your `asyncHandler()` function will only run when that "auth state change" event happens. After setting up that handler, your `console.log()` will run *immediately*; it doesn't wait for that event to occur.

Comment: Re "hoisting" -- hoisting isn't the issue here. It's timing. (Side note: It seems unlikely that `user` in your example is a promise. If it isn't, there's no reason to `await` it.)